# Firebase Hosting not clearing CDN cache on deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase Hosting for a single page application, and I have recently updated some security-related headers via firebase.json:

```
/* example excerpt of firebase.json */
"hosting": {
  "headers": [{
    "source": "**",
    "headers": [{
      "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
      "value": "<csp here>"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I haven't otherwise changed the application or its resources (JavaScript files, etc.)

I've rebuilt and redeployed my application with

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting
```

I am expecting that the act of deploying should invalidate the CDN cache for static resources served by Firebase Hosting, based on this statement from the [Firebase Hosting Cache documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache):

> If you redeploy your site's content, Firebase Hosting automatically
> clears all your cached static content across the CDN until the next
> request.

But I'm quite sure that's not happening, at least not consistently.

When I "shift-reload" the application in my browser, I can see via Chrome developer tools that the browser is issuing a proper GET for my application's service worker code (https://example.com/service-worker.js), but based on the response headers the request has been handled by the CDN:

```
cache-control: no-cache
x-cache: HIT
x-cache-hits: 1
x-served-by: cache-sea4425-SEA
```

Crucially, the change that I made to the security header via firebase.json is NOT present in the returned resource -- it is apparently re-using a CDN-cached version of the resource, complete with cached (and obsolete) headers.

So it seems to me that the CDN cache is perhaps not cleared when the newly-deployed static content hasn't changed? Or at the very least it does not appear that the CDN cache is invalidated in a timely manner, as implied by the documentation.

How can I ensure that when changes are made to resource headers via firebase.json, the CDN will invalidate old versions of static content?

Comment: I can confirm that if I use "Cache-Control: no-store" rather than "Cache-Control: no-cache" for my service-worker.js, I get the expected results. i.e., the CDN falls back to the origin. But of course this is not a general solution, and seems counter to the documentation.